# How can I insert a key/value pair into each dictionary contained in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I'm working on a script to check a list of email addresses to see if they have been reported as compromised.  The return is json data which is essentially a list of dictionaries.

For each compromised account I want to insert the key/value pair "Email" :  into each dictionary in the returned list of dictionaries then export that to a CSV file.  I'm currently having trouble inserting the key/value pairs.

example data that is returned separated by a newline for readability:

> [{'Name': 'BTSec', 'Title': 'Bitcoin Security Forum Gmail Dump', 'Domain': 'forum.btcsec.com', 'BreachDate': '2014-01-09', 'AddedDate': '2014-09-10T20:30:11Z', 'ModifiedDate': '2014-09-10T20:30:11Z', 'PwnCount': 4789599, 'Description': 'In September 2014, a large dump of nearly 5M usernames and passwords was posted to a Russian Bitcoin forum. Whilst commonly reported as 5M "Gmail passwords", the dump also contained 123k yandex.ru addresses. Whilst the origin of the breach remains unclear, the breached credentials were confirmed by multiple source as correct, albeit a number of years old.', 'LogoType': 'svg', 'DataClasses': ['Email addresses', 'Passwords'], 'IsVerified': True, 'IsFabricated': False, 'IsSensitive': False, 'IsRetired': False, 'IsSpamList': False}
>
> {'Name': 'ExploitIn', 'Title': 'Exploit.In', 'Domain': '', 'BreachDate': '2016-10-13', 'AddedDate': '2017-05-06T07:03:18Z', 'ModifiedDate': '2017-05-06T07:03:18Z', 'PwnCount': 593427119, 'Description': 'In late 2016, a huge list of email address and password pairs appeared in a "combo list" referred to as "Exploit.In". The list contained 593 million unique email addresses, many with multiple different passwords hacked from various online systems. The list was broadly circulated and used for "credential stuffing", that is attackers employ it in an attempt to identify other online systems where the account owner had reused their password. For detailed background on this incident, read Password reuse, credential stuffing and another billion records in Have I been pwned.', 'LogoType': 'svg', 'DataClasses': ['Email addresses', 'Passwords'], 'IsVerified': False, 'IsFabricated': False, 'IsSensitive': False, 'IsRetired': False, 'IsSpamList': False}
>
> {'Name': 'LinkedIn', 'Title': 'LinkedIn', 'Domain': 'linkedin.com', 'BreachDate': '2012-05-05', 'AddedDate': '2016-05-21T21:35:40Z', 'ModifiedDate': '2016-05-21T21:35:40Z', 'PwnCount': 164611595, 'Description': 'In May 2016, LinkedIn had 164 million email addresses and passwords exposed. Originally hacked in 2012, the data remained out of sight until being offered for sale on a dark market site 4 years later. The passwords in the breach were stored as SHA1 hashes without salt, the vast majority of which were quickly cracked in the days following the release of the data.', 'LogoType': 'svg', 'DataClasses': ['Email addresses', 'Passwords'], 'IsVerified': True, 'IsFabricated': False, 'IsSensitive': False, 'IsRetired': False, 'IsSpamList': False}]

Here is my current code:

```
def main():
if address != "None":
    checkAddress(address)
elif filename != "None":
    email = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open(filename)] # strip the newlines
    for email in email:
        checkAddress(email)
else:
    for email in lstEmail:
        checkAddress(email)

def checkAddress(email):
sleep = rate # Reset default acceptable rate
check = requests.get("https://" + server + "/api/v2/breachedaccount/" + email + "?includeUnverified=true",
             headers = headers,
             proxies = proxies,
             verify = sslVerify)
if str(check.status_code) == "404": # The address has not been breached.
    print (OKGREEN + "[i] " + email + " has not been breached." + ENDC)
    time.sleep(sleep) # sleep so that we don't trigger the rate limit
    return False
elif str(check.status_code) == "200": # The address has been breached!
    print (FAILRED + "[!] " + email + " has been breached!" + ENDC)
    data = (check.json())


    for i in data:
        data[i].append( [{'test':'test'}])
        print (i)
        print ('\n') # Temp \n for readability


    time.sleep(sleep) # sleep so that we don't trigger the rate limit
    return True
```

And here is the error I'm currently getting:

```
[!] j.doe@gmail.com has been breached!
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "hibp2csv.py", line 95, in <module>
     main()
File "hibp2csv.py", line 52, in main
   checkAddress(email)
File "hibp2csv.py", line 70, in checkAddress
     data[i].append( [{'test':'test'}])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this error because you're iterating over the list `data` using elements, not index, so `i` is going to be each element of `data` at every iteration and when you call `data[i]` you're passing the dict instead of index.

To fix that you can just modify your `for` statement to `for i in range(len(data))`.

Also, use `dict.update({"key": "value"})` to update a dict.

Comment: Yeah I caught the whole iterating over the list after I posted... thanks this worked perfect.